# Compiling in Visual Studio 2015 - 'Cannot start debugging because the debug target is missing'

Tags: .net, visual-studio

The Visual Studio instance I use displays:

> Cannot start debugging because the debug target is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the outputpath and AssemblyName appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly.

What does this mean?

Comment: bcuz? pls? Your version of VS indeed is broken if it displays that. Anyway, you say *compiling* doesn't work, but the message says the problem is in *debugging*. So did you try setting the Outputpath etc?

Comment: "Please build the project and retry." If you cannot follow the instructions in this error message, you are going to have a difficult time writing programs. Learning by hacking around is rarely successful. Consider getting a book that teaches you programming .NET applications using Visual Studio. Check Amazon for suggestions. Chances are *very* good that the real source of this problem is compilation errors that need to be fixed before the project can be built (and therefore run). Check the "Error List" floating tool window.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools > Options`, expand the Projects/Solutions node in the tree on the left hand side, and click on "Build and Run" under Projects/Solutions. You should see a dropdown labelled "On Run, when projects are out of date:" Make sure that is set to either "Always build" or "Prompt to build".

Rebuild the project, have a look at the output folders /bin/Debug /bin/Release to see that the required assembly is definitely there. Check the Configuration Manager configure to run, set as the start up project.